# Check if multiple items are selected, and show if items are the same

Tags: delphi, tlistview

Delphi Listview is loaded with music information. When you select multiple items from the Listview, it will show `<multi>`. How can you select multiple items and the **value is the same**, showing its value instead of `<multi>`?

Unit1.asp

```
unit Unit1;
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    ListView1: TListView;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    strTrack: TEdit;
    strArtist: TEdit;
    LTrack: TLabel;
    LBand: TLabel;
    strSong: TEdit;
    strAlbum: TEdit;
    LSong: TLabel;
    LAlbum: TLabel;
    LYear: TLabel;
    strYear: TEdit;
    strCheck: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
      Selected: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Column: TListColumn;
  Item: TListItem;
begin
ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  Panel1.Align := alClient;
  ListView1.Align := alClient;
  Column := ListView1.Columns.Add;
  Column.Caption := 'ID';
  Column.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
  Column.Width := 60;

  Column := ListView1.Columns.Add;
  Column.Caption := 'Band Name';
  Column.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
  Column.Width := 300;

    Column := ListView1.Columns.Add;
  Column.Caption := 'Song Name';
  Column.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
  Column.Width := 300;

    Column := ListView1.Columns.Add;
  Column.Caption := 'Album Name';
  Column.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
  Column.Width := 300;

  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := '07';
  Item.SubItems.Add('KISS');
  Item.SubItems.Add('Tears are Falling');
  Item.SubItems.Add('Asylum');
   Item.SubItems.Add('1985');


   Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
    Item.Caption := '08';
  Item.SubItems.Add('W.A.S.P.');
  Item.SubItems.Add('The Idol');
  Item.SubItems.Add('The Crimson Idol ');
   Item.SubItems.Add('1992');

   Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
    Item.Caption := '04';
  Item.SubItems.Add('Bobaflex');
  Item.SubItems.Add('Hey You');
  Item.SubItems.Add('Eloquent Demons');
  Item.SubItems.Add('2017');

   Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
      Item.Caption := '04';
  Item.SubItems.Add('Blacktop Mojo');
  Item.SubItems.Add('Prodigal');
  Item.SubItems.Add('Burn the Ships');
   Item.SubItems.Add('2017');

   Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
      Item.Caption := '08';
  Item.SubItems.Add('Whitechapel');
  Item.SubItems.Add('Orphan');
  Item.SubItems.Add('Kin');
   Item.SubItems.Add('2021');

  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption := '09';
  Item.SubItems.Add('KISS');
  Item.SubItems.Add('Dreamin');
  Item.SubItems.Add('Psycho Circus');
   Item.SubItems.Add('1999');
ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Selected: Boolean);
  var
  ls: TListItem;
begin       // LS has to be here, if not, you will receive  an access violation when you click on items after the first item.
ls := ListView1.Selected;
 if Assigned(ls) then
  begin
  strTrack.Text := ListView1.Selected.Caption;
    strArtist.Text := ListView1.Selected.SubItems[0];
    strSong.Text := ListView1.Selected.SubItems[1];
    strAlbum.Text := ListView1.Selected.SubItems[2];
    strYear.Text := ListView1.Selected.SubItems[3];

     ls := ListView1.GetNextItem(ls, sdAll, [isSelected]);
     while Assigned(ls) do
    begin
    strTrack.Text := '<multi>';
    strArtist.Text := '<multi>';
    strSong.Text := '<multi>';
    strAlbum.Text := '<multi>';
    strYear.Text := '<multi>';
     ls := ListView1.GetNextItem(ls, sdAll, [isSelected]);
    end;
   end;
end;
end.
```

Project1.dpr

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Unit1.dfm

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 523
  ClientWidth = 626
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  TextHeight = 15
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 40
    Top = 224
    Width = 529
    Height = 249
    TabOrder = 0
    object ListView1: TListView
      Left = 40
      Top = 48
      Width = 425
      Height = 150
      Columns = <>
      MultiSelect = True
      RowSelect = True
      TabOrder = 0
      ViewStyle = vsReport
      OnSelectItem = ListView1SelectItem
    end
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 626
    Height = 97
    Align = alTop
    TabOrder = 1
    object LTrack: TLabel
      Left = 184
      Top = 34
      Width = 37
      Height = 15
      Caption = 'Track #'
    end
    object LBand: TLabel
      Left = 7
      Top = 13
      Width = 27
      Height = 15
      Caption = 'Band'
    end
    object LSong: TLabel
      Left = 8
      Top = 42
      Width = 27
      Height = 15
      Caption = 'Song'
    end
    object LAlbum: TLabel
      Left = 184
      Top = 8
      Width = 36
      Height = 15
      Caption = 'Album'
    end
    object LYear: TLabel
      Left = 402
      Top = 8
      Width = 22
      Height = 15
      Caption = 'Year'
    end
    object strTrack: TEdit
      Left = 227
      Top = 34
      Width = 166
      Height = 23
      TabOrder = 0
    end
    object strArtist: TEdit
      Left = 40
      Top = 5
      Width = 121
      Height = 23
      TabOrder = 1
    end
    object strSong: TEdit
      Left = 41
      Top = 34
      Width = 121
      Height = 23
      TabOrder = 2
    end
    object strAlbum: TEdit
      Left = 226
      Top = 5
      Width = 167
      Height = 23
      TabOrder = 3
    end
    object strYear: TEdit
      Left = 430
      Top = 5
      Width = 43
      Height = 23
      TabOrder = 4
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This "question" (like your follow up) also doesn't contain one single question, only issues and prosa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to understand exactly what you are asking for, but I *think* you are looking for something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Selected: Boolean);
var
  ls: TListItem;
  sTrack, sArtist, sSong, sAlbum, sYear: string; 

  procedure CheckForMulti(var selectedStr: string; const value: string);
  begin
    if selectedStr = '' then
      selectedStr := value
    else if selectedStr <> value then
      selectedStr := '<multi>';
  end;

begin
  ls := ListView1.Selected;
  while Assigned(ls) do
  begin
    CheckForMulti(sTrack,  ls.Caption);
    CheckForMulti(sArtist, ls.SubItems[0]);
    CheckForMulti(sSong,   ls.SubItems[1]);
    CheckForMulti(sAlbum,  ls.SubItems[2]);
    CheckForMulti(sYear,   ls.SubItems[3]);
    ls := ListView1.GetNextItem(ls, sdAll, [isSelected]);
  end;
  strTrack.Text  := sTrack;
  strArtist.Text := sArtist;
  strSong.Text   := sSong;
  strAlbum.Text  := sAlbum;
  strYear.Text   := sYear;
end;
```

Comment: That was it.
And you understood it perfectly. I ran it and had to change the THEN to a DO, but other than that, it worked like a charm. Thank you so much. I changed so that other values could march on each other, and they all worked. Now time to add it to the project and work on the Save procedure, that is the next part.

Comment: Remy, once again. Thank you. I was able to implement it into my MP3 project, and it works like a charm. Thank you, and have a rockin rest of the weekend.

Comment: Hey, Remy. Could you please tell me how to do this? I need to get the path to the file, which is on SubItem[7]. If I try to add code to where your code is, it gives an Access Violation error. Here are the two different codes. One uses your code and the other mine. =========== strTest.Text := string(ListItem.SubItems.Add(FileName)); (OR)
strTest.Text := ls.SubItems[7];  ========

Comment: Forgot to mention. I can get the path through your code.but the check turns it into [multi] and I need the path to remain it's original.

Comment: You are asking a completely new and unrelated question, so it should be in its own separate post.

Comment: Hey, Remy. I completely rewrote the question and changed the code. As it was NOT clearly done, and I did not think that the demo code would not be the same as the actual code. So, here is a revised code that works with MP3 files. https://stackoverflow.com/q/78175663/2031172